# How do I know what program 'xdg-open' will use to open a directory? (Python)

Tags: python, linux, xdgutils

So I have this:

```
def openSegmentDirectory(self):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.startfile(self.segmentPath)
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', self.segmentPath])
    else:
        #for mac
        os.system('open "%s"' % self.segmentPath)
```

But when using it on linux, the system attempts to open the directory in firefox, which I don't want. How can I change this?

Comment: You might want to look at xdg-mime default option -- http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html

Comment: But is this changed on a local system level? I need something to put into my python code to ensure it works on any system that may run it.

Comment: It uses your default program for opening files

Comment: But I have Dolphin and several other file managers installed, and I never get Firefox unless I do this in python with this code. It is opening Firefox as a last resort and I don't know why. I'm using RHEL

Comment: So `xdg-open /home` from a shell does not use firefox?

Comment: No, you''re right, it also acts this way from terminal. Even so, I need a universal solution, since any machine may have this issue.